# Android Custom Dialog (DialogFragment)

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have the following `DialogFragment` with the following method :

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.buddy_challenge, null));

    this.title = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.challenge_title);
    this.challenge = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.challenge_button);
    this.at = (AutoCompleteTextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.chall_ex);

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "getAllEx"));
    new ServerCallEx().execute(params);
    return builder.create();
}
```

The custom layout inflates properly but if I try changing the TextView or try attach an Adapter to the AutoCompleteTextView I get a null pointer exception and can't figure out why (don't know why the `getActivity.findViewByID()` is not working). Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this with :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buddy_challenge, container, false);
    this.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.challenge_title);
    this.at = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.chall_ex);
    this.at.setThreshold(1);
    return view;
}
```

and calling this to remove the title:

```
challDialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buddy_challenge, null);
    builder.setView(view);

    this.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.challenge_title);
```

Regards.

Comment: .setContentView() is not a method in the AlertDialog builder class!

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't created it yet. You called `create` and return the `View` at the end of the method, but you're trying to do `findViewById` before that.

Comment: I tried calling the line in onViewCreated() aswell as outside of the dialog where I call dialog.show() but still have no luck! any ideas why?

Comment: Instead of trying to find the view from the activity, try to find it from the fragment's view. If you want to do it in `onViewCreated`, try replacing `getActivity().findViewById` with `getView().findViewById`.